Does making a ground plane and a power plane on a PCB make the board behave like a large capacitor?
If someone designs a 4 layer PCB and makes a power and ground plane, does the PCB act like a capacitor? If it does, would it allow the designer to omit decoupling capacitors from the design?

Related question: Can we build capacitors on a PCB board?

The power and ground planes can even be treated as a transmission line with its own characteristic impedance, the best power integrity is achieved when it's matched to the transient load impedance - although it's not practical and is mostly an academic exercise. One practical application is terminating the edge of a PCB with a large number of SMD resistors and capacitors, the resistors are set to the impedance of the power-ground pair so electromagnetic energy is dissipated instead of radiated, and the capacitor blocks DC. This solution is superior to via fencing as it eliminates reflections.

It would act as a small capacitor regarding capacitance, only large in area.
The capacitance of the planes will help, but distributing that small capacitance over a large area means it will only be somewhat effective.
You still need bypass capacitors on each chip.
As an example, a 10cm x 10cm PCB, with ground and supply planes separated by 1.065mm of PCB core material with dielectric constant of 4.6, the capacitance as a single lump is only 382 pF.

Is there a difference between bypass capacitors and decoupling capacitors? Am I using incorrect terminology?

@AlexHeinle Good question. At least I tend to use bypass caps and decoupling caps interchangeably. To some people there might be a slight difference in the term.

@AlexHeinle: Decoupling reduces noise generated by one circuit from interfering with adjacent circuits. Bypass allows a pathway around a circuit to prevent the noise entering the circuit. A single capacitor can accomplish both tasks at the same time, so the terms are often used interchangeably.

Scientific American had a N2 gas laser project back in the 1970s that used capacitors fabricated on a PCB to store energy necessary for the laser pulse (enough energy to fire a spark gap).  There is a whole lot of experimentation still going on with similar designs; just plug "Scientific American Nitrogen Laser" into your favorite search engine.

The amount of capacitance that can be achieved between two layers of a PCB tend to be low. For example 4mil separation with FR4 dielectric gives about 250pF/sq inch. (Calculate interplane capacitance)
However it can be useful as a decoupling capacitor as it is possible to achieve extremely low effective series inductance of the order of  100 picoHenries which is an advantage in high frequency circuits.
By comparison an 0603 surface mount ceramic capacitor will have a self inductance of about 1nH, with an 0402 a bit less.
Very thin PCB substrate materials are available to enhance the effect
For example:
FaradFlex

C=epsilon*A/d. Do the calculation for your particular geometry.
It will be small compared to decoupling capacitances.
